# What is the meaning of 'live' in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And I love you so
> The people ask me how?
> How I've lived til now?
> I tell them I don't know?

Can you tell me what the word live means?

Comment: Presumably 'how I've managed to remain alive'.

Comment: Read it as a verb.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from that extract. It could mean how you conduct yourself in life, or how you find food/money to stay alive. There are a lot of meanings: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live

Comment: @StuartF It's the lyrics to the Don McLean song "And I Love You So". https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/donmclean/andiloveyouso.html

Answer (score 1):

The song [And I Love You So](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/donmclean/andiloveyouso.html) is about a person who has just fallen in love, and their life has begun again.

"begun again" implies that they lost a previous love, although it's hard to tell whether the previous love died or just left them. When that happened, their life became extremely lonely, and they felt like they were dead.

When people ask "how they've lived till now", they're asking how they've managed to survive this horrible loneliness.